# How to save report filters and making it available for executing and scheduling

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, postgresql

I have a use case where I have to Add query params to APIs call, and save it accordingly.
Meaning- I have one report to Add, which gives multiple filters that to be saved. (Some of them are pre-defined and others can be added) which could be saved and it could run to generate report or to schedule it.
How here I am using postgres sql as DB. How can I solve such scenarios, If say saving into db then what's the best way to do such operations? I have a db table where I am storing Report name and descriptions. But how can I add such Filters and Save it? And next time the user just Schedule or generate report with saved filters.

Below are the images for better understanding of the scenario.

1. The Image of where List displayed of saved reports
   [image]
2. The Image where user can Add custom report using available filters.
   [image]

Not sure the best way to handle such scenarios, where I have to add multiple of filters and save it accordingly.

Can anyone help me here with the approach to handle such things? Like saving in DB or how it could work the best.
Thanks

Edit-  Something like JIRA, can save the filters and directly apply it. Something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have control over your web application and that it will translate what users input into SQL queries, just create a data structure that both your UI and your data tier can understand and store it in a table using the [JSON or JSONB datatype](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-json.html).